# How can I assign a value to a generic parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I want to write code that reads and writes data to a stream for packet serialization.

Classify data types and write and read data through Bitconverter.

I wrote this simply as below.

```
public int WritePrimitiveType(ArraySegment<byte> stream, int offset, object data)
{
    string data_type = data.GetType().Name;
    switch (data_type)
    {
        case "Boolean":
            Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes((Boolean)data), 0, stream.Array, stream.Offset + offset, sizeof(Boolean));
            return sizeof(Boolean);
        case "Byte":
            Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes((Byte)data), 0, stream.Array, stream.Offset + offset, sizeof(Byte));
            return sizeof(Byte);       
        case "Int32":
            Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes((Int32)data), 0, stream.Array, stream.Offset + offset, sizeof(Int32));
            return sizeof(Int32);        
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}


public int ReadPrimitiveType<T>(ArraySegment<byte> stream, int offset, ref T data)
{
    switch (typeof(T).Name)
    {
        case "Boolean":
            data = (T)((object)BitConverter.ToBoolean(stream.Array, stream.Offset + offset));
            return sizeof(Boolean);
        case "Byte":
            data = (T)((object)BitConverter.ToInt16(stream.Array, stream.Offset + offset));
            return sizeof(Byte);       
        case "Int32":
            data = (T)((object)BitConverter.ToInt32(stream.Array, stream.Offset + offset));
            return sizeof(Int32);
        default:
            data = default(T);
            return 0;
    }
}
```

It appears to have been written in an immature way.

How to properly write such code in C#? I would like to improve the above code.

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally wrong with that code.  We C and C++ coders are used to having our variables be very malleable -- we can pretend they are any type we want from statement to statement.  C# doesn't do that, and it makes that kind of code very awkward.  It's one of the things that kept me from embracing C#.

Comment: You have an exact set of allowed types, each of which requires a different implementation, and each of which requires the caller to specify the type explicitly. So you should write a set of polymorphic functions. This is not a problem that requires generics.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is to forget about using generics at all. Just write the 6 functions with the same names and let the C# compiler work out which one to call based on the provided data argument;

```cs
public int WritePrimitiveType(ArraySegment<byte> stream, int offset, bool data){ ... }
public int WritePrimitiveType(ArraySegment<byte> stream, int offset, byte data){ ... }
public int WritePrimitiveType(ArraySegment<byte> stream, int offset, int data){ ... }
public int ReadPrimitiveType(ArraySegment<byte> stream, int offset, ref bool data){ ... }
public int ReadPrimitiveType(ArraySegment<byte> stream, int offset, ref byte data){ ... }
public int ReadPrimitiveType(ArraySegment<byte> stream, int offset, ref int data){ ... }
```

If you really want to use generics, you could use generic delegates to call the type specific `BitConverter` methods.

```cs
public static class Converter<T>{
    private static Func<byte[], int, T> reader;
    private static Action<byte[], int, T> writer;
    static Converter(){
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool)){
            reader =  (Func<byte[], int, T>)(object) new Func<byte[], int, bool>(BitConverter.ToBoolean);
            writer = ...
        }
        ... etc
    }
    public static int ReadPrimitiveType(ArraySegment<byte> stream, int offset, ref T data){
        data = reader(stream.Array, stream.Offset + offset);
        return sizeof(T);
    }

}
```

At least this will avoid boxing and unboxing on every read.

Answer (score 1):

You can generalize your code and replace the `switch` statement with the `Dictionary` or other data structure. This will simplify the situation a lot, but may make the code slower and in some cases less readable.

Here we have introduced the the special `ProcessingData` class to store conversion functions for each type. Then we filled the `Dictionary` with instances of such a type - one instance for each target type we want to read or write.

And now we can just do a dictionary lookup and use the given instance of `ProcessingData` to process the given data.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, ProcessingData> Processors = new()
{
    [typeof(bool)] = new
    (
        readFunc: (s, o) => BitConverter.ToBoolean(s, o),
        writeFunc: d => BitConverter.GetBytes((bool)d),
        size: sizeof(bool)
    ),
    [typeof(byte)] = new
    (
        readFunc: (s, o) => BitConverter.ToBoolean(s, o),
        writeFunc: d => new[] { (byte)d },
        size: sizeof(byte)
    ),
    [typeof(int)] = new
    (
        readFunc: (s, o) => BitConverter.ToInt32(s, o),
        writeFunc: d => BitConverter.GetBytes((int)d),
        size: sizeof(int)
    ),
};

public int WritePrimitiveType(ArraySegment<byte> stream, int offset, object data)
{
    if (Processors.TryGetValue(data.GetType(), out var processor))
    {
        return processor.Write(stream, offset, data);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public int ReadPrimitiveType<T>(ArraySegment<byte> stream, int offset, ref T? data)
{
    if (Processors.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var processor))
    {
        return processor.Read(stream, offset, out data);
    }
    else
    {
        data = default;
        return 0;
    }

}


internal class ProcessingData
{
    private readonly Func<byte[], int, object> _readFunc;
    private readonly Func<object, byte[]> _writeFunc;
    private readonly int _size;

    public ProcessingData(Func<byte[], int, object> readFunc,
                          Func<object, byte[]> writeFunc, int size)
    {
        _readFunc = readFunc;
        _writeFunc = writeFunc;
        _size = size;
    }

    public int Read<T>(ArraySegment<byte> stream, int offset, out T data)
    {
        data = (T)_readFunc(stream.Array, stream.Offset + offset);
        return _size;
    }
    public int Write(ArraySegment<byte> stream, int offset, object data)
    {
        Array.Copy(_writeFunc(data), 0, stream.Array, stream.Offset + offset, _size);
        return _size;
    }
}
```

You can try to play with generics to go from the `object`-based code in the `ProcessingData` to generic one. And this should significantly improve the readability of the dictionary initialization code because you will be able to write just `BitConverter.ToBoolean` (method group) instead of `(s, o) => BitConverter.ToBoolean(s, o)` labmda. But I'm not sure if such a generics-based approach is possible.